# Required different PHP project login before login to my PHP project - Why?

Tags: php, html, mysql, authentication

I have a PHP project which is in the localhost for now.

The issue that I'm facing is when I open the url and try to login, it doesn't let me to login and it will revert back to the same page. But if I try to login other PHP project first, then login to my PHP project it will be able to login.

So what is the reason for this issue? Can anyone assist me?

**Code**

```
<?php 


 include "../setting/config.php";

 session_start();

 if(!isset($_POST['login']))
 {
    $_SESSION['test'];
  
}

if(isset($_POST['login'])){
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    //ADMIN
    $query1 = "SELECT * FROM umd_login WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'";
    $query_run=mysqli_query($conn, $query1);
    $level = mysqli_fetch_array($query_run);

if(count(fetchAll($query1)) > 0){ //this is to catch unknown error.
                  foreach(fetchAll($query1) as $row){
                    if ($row['username'] == $username && $row['password'] == $password) {
                        $_SESSION['test'] = true;
                        $_SESSION['username']= $_POST['username'];
                        if($level['user_level_id'] == "1"){
                            header('location:UMD_home.php');
                            exit;
                        }
                    } else {
                        alert();
                    }
                }
            }
            function alert(){
                echo "<script>alert('Invalid username or password. Please try again.')</script>";
            }

        }


if (isset($_POST['login'])) {
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    //UMD,CMD
    $query2   = "SELECT * FROM registered_accounts WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'";
    $query_run=mysqli_query($conn, $query2);
    $level = mysqli_fetch_array($query_run);


    if (count(fetchAll($query2)) > 0) { //this is to catch unknown error.
        foreach (fetchAll($query2) as $row) {
            if ($row['username'] == $username && $row['password'] == $password) {
                $_SESSION['test'] = true;
                $_SESSION['username']= $_POST['username'];
                if($level['level'] == "CMD"){
                    header('location:CMD_home.php');
                    exit;
                }else if($level['level'] == "UMD"){
                    header('location:UMD_home2.php');
                    exit();
                }
            } else {
                alert();
            }
        }
    } else {
        alert();
    }

}
    
?>

<form action="<?= $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="post">
    <input type="text" class="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" value="" required autofocus>
    <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password" value="" required autofocus>
    <div class="submit"><input type="submit" value="Login" name="login"></div>
</form>
```

Comment: are these projects have different url? is there same file shared?

Comment: Hi @Rafee - Thank you for your reply. No, different files and url.. Non related projects.

Comment: You are open to SQL injections and XSS injections. Please consult a tutorial. Also hash your user passwords.

Comment: 1) You never set a value for `$_SESSION['login']` so you'll always be redirected to `test.php`. 2) Each of your apps should set their own session **names** to avoid conflicts when sharing hosts. See https://www.php.net/manual/function.session-name.php

Comment: Hi @Phil - Thank you for your reply. I've edited the code as above, please assist to check. Do you mean in that way?

Comment: No, not at all. Where you had `!isset($_SESSION['login'])`, you should be checking for `$_SESSION['test']` or `$_SESSION['username']` as those are the session properties you **do** set. Alternatively, you could always set `$_SESSION['login'] = true;` when you perform a successful login. And as I said before, set a unique **session name** for each of your PHP apps

Comment: @Phil - Please check the above edited code. I'm still quite confusing a bit. Could you please assist to show me the code as the below comment. It will be very helpful. Please.

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing an access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. Any modern [development framework](https://www.cloudways.com/blog/best-php-frameworks/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with an [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/master/authentication) built-in, and there are [authentication libraries](http://phprbac.net/) you can use. At the absolute least follow [recommended security best practices](http://www.phptherightway.com/#security) and **never store passwords as plain-text** or a weak hash like **SHA1 or MD5**.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add any data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or data *of any kind* directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: Note: The [object-oriented interface to `mysqli`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.connections.php) is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface where missing a single `i` can cause trouble. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era and should not be used in new code. Additionally the procedural interface has less rigorous error checking and reporting, frustrating debugging efforts.

Comment: I don't see  mysqli_real_escape_string.

Comment: I don't see  csrf_token.

Answer (score 0):

//start a session on the topand make a create a session

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['email'])){
   header('location:dashboard.php');
}

?>
```

add this code to the top of the login form page
and i think this will solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

I've added:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['login']))  
{  
  $_SESSION['login'] = true;
}
```

and it is working now. Thank you everyone. You all helped me well. Have a nice day.

Answer (score -1):

1. You can login, from other project is because you have a Session variable with the same name in both projects.
2. as Ravin said, on line 3, $_SESSION['login'] si always null (is not initialized).
   Use instead:
   if(!isset($_POST['login'])){

Comment: Hi @Razvan Traian - Thank you for your reply. I've edited the code as above, please assist to check. Do you mean in that way?

Comment: Yes, something like. It is working ? I don't get why you initalize $_SESSION['test'] only for if POST is sent, you can initialize it as false without the IF. Also as a suggestion, if you have more projects with same key names such as $_['username'] try use $_SESSION['project1_username']; Other concern is that you don't hash your password and you put it plain into your database.

Comment: Sorry, it was Phil that answer that before... that you never initialized $_SESSION['login'].